# extjs, is it possible to compress load ext-all.js?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a website that's using the extjs librar. Exactly I just need grid, ajax and tree component.
My project is used nationally, and to avoid problems due to low bandwith in the some regions, I must to make it as light as possible.

When I use the developer tools in chrome, my site is too heavy. Especially when loading ext-all.js. It take 3,9 minutes to load(@512kbps), (even when I remove my own images and css from the website).

Is there a way to compress it? Or to just load the tree, grid and ajax components?
I was googling.. and I got this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-all.js?compression=gzip"></script>
```

but, it didn't help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the page that shows you how to build custom versions of ext-js.  http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Building_Ext_From_Source

They had a link to an online builder that would customize the download but it's been taken down. The link mentioned still points to good resources like [JsBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/js-builder/), the tool they use to generate ext-all.js and the other packages in the distribution. Just open the ext.jsb to see how it works

[image: JS Builder Screen Shot]

You'll need to figure out the dependencies on your own though, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'd estimate that at 512k, the extjs load should be around 30 s - 1 minute.

If you're looking at a 4 minute load time, your time is probably spent somewhere other than the download of the library. Are you sure it's the size of your download, or even extjs that is the problem? Could it be that your webserver is under heavy load, or that you're dealing with a latency issue?

As far as reducing the size of the library - there isn't much more you can do. The library is provided in minified format, and stripping it further is not recommended. Zipping it up only means you'll have to unzip at the other end once downloaded, and doesn't buy you that much load time with a library that's already very small.

Comment: hmmm.. maybe my bandwith not exactly 512kbps.. i use modem to test it.. and i dont use any internet service at the moment...

but my bandwith is not big problem,... i'm trying to make my web looks good even at 64 kbps... but thanks,..

Comment: Zipping does help a whole lot! Specially at slow speeds!