# how to deflate js file in nginX?

Tags: compression, nginx

I’m looking for "how to compress load time js file" and I try the solution of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055756/extjs-is-it-posible-to-compres-load-ext-all-js) (I’m using Extjs).

My friend suggest [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?84577-Compress-all-output-and-speed-up-JS-file-download-Apache&s=2716cbb182267e56e044387b75a44909) too. But, it use Apache as web server. Anybody know how to do the trick in NGINX??

My hosting uses nginx as web server and i don’t know anything about web server configuration.

sorry, if my english bad..

Comment: I don't think this is anyway related to extjs tag.. so I am removing it

Comment: very good... keep it up brother :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you do not know anything about web server configuration, I am assuming you also do not know how/where to edit the config file.

The nginx conf file is located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (verified in Ubuntu 12.04)

By default, nginx gzip module is enabled. So check from this service whether it is enabled on not [using an online tool like this](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/).

If it is disabled, add this before server {...} entry in nginx.conf

```
# output compression saves bandwidth
gzip  on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;

# make sure gzip does not lose large gzipped js or css files
# see http://blog.leetsoft.com/2007/07/25/nginx-gzip-ssl.html
gzip_buffers 16 8k;

# Disable gzip for certain browsers.
gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)”;
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but i find my nginx conf in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf...
thanks for your help

Comment: `text/html` is included in `gzip_types` by default and will show a warning if you include it again.

Comment: I was wondering why just `gzip on` didn't take care of this by itself and the answer is that only `text/html` is on by default. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/

Answer (score 2):

I make this configuration in my nginx.config you need

```
gzip  on;
location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
  gzip_static on;
  expires     1w;
  add_header  Cache-Control public;
  add_header  Last-Modified "";
  add_header  ETag "";
}
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|svg)$ {
  gzip_static on;
  expires     1w;
  add_header  Cache-Control public;
  add_header  Last-Modified "";
  add_header  ETag "";
}
```

​

Comment: note that that gzip_static is not available in nginx by default. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the nginx [HTTP gzip](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule) or the nginx [HTTP gzip static](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipStaticModule) module. The static module would be helpful for content like your JavaScript libraries that rarely changes, saving you needless re-compression for every client.